# Why cell's childs' height changes during scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using `UIController` (to reuse cells with new information - with another model class instance) and custom `UICollectionViewCell` during scrolling (from top to bottom with finger) cells label's height changes from 54.0
to 84.5 (see output)

Why does it happen?

**Test Code**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyItemCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyItemCollectionViewCell

    print("uilabel height \(cell.mylabel.frame.height)")

    return cell
}
```

**Output**

```
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 54.0
uilabel height 84.5
uilabel height 84.5
uilabel height 84.5
uilabel height 84.5
```

**Cell**

```
class MyItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mylabel: UILabel!

    func setItem(_ item: MyItem) {
        mylabel.text = item.name
    }
}
```

Comment: you may have different itemSize for every cell

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't change size, I have only one template for cell and its childs in storyboard

Comment: Do you mean it change visibly or just in ‘print’? Also where do you call ‘setItem’, is it in ‘cellForItemAtIndexPath’? I don’t see any in your code.

Comment: Another point, ‘cellForItemAtIndexPath’ might not show the correct height, so don’t rely your ‘print’ to debug cell height there.

Comment: @aunnnn  see `cellForItemAt indexPath`

Comment: @aunnnn why so? I need to get real height, I want to change programmatically something using this height value

Comment: @aunnnn are you talking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557680/4548520

Comment: @user25 Normally ‘cellForItem’ is meant to set content/viewmodel to a cell only, and the layout is done later behind the scene by uicollectionview. So we should never rely on any calls to ‘.frame’ inside this function as it’s not correct yet. Btw, do you use Autolayout or setting the height manually somewhere?

Comment: @aunnnn I use autolayout in storyboard, uilabel always takes 33% height of cell

Comment: @aunnnn I also want to auto resize font size of uilabel, but there is no such option in storyboard for font size only for view width, height, so I'm trying to do it programmatically `let fontSize = cell.mylabel.frame.height*0.5`,
        `cell.mylabel.font = cell.mylabel.font.withSize(fontSize)`

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: @Moosa what exactly? I think I added enough code to explain. You can create simple example yourself, as I understood already such behaviour is normal for  `cellForItemAt`

Comment: Are you use from UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be the problem while redrawing the screen , the collection view is not reloaded.It seems same like this post [CollectionView Cell changing size after scrolling - AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886666/collectionview-cell-changing-size-after-scrolling-autolayout) .

Comment: I don't know what is outerCell - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887585/4548520, those methods don't exist for `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Its nothing just an identifier for cell in your above code.